# Can't access elements after second replacement of Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments in my application.The first one replaces other on the screen and it gathers data , sends it to previous fragment and go back the first fragment. But once fragment displayed, I cannot change components features(e.g. text of edittext) and when I try to read data(gettext from edittext) it gives data as very first situation of edittext)

Related part of code:

```
//Both Classes have this fnc:
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction  =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
//Part From 1st Class
fragmentSearch.fragmentAdd = FragmentAdd.this;// I give my current fragment's class to 2nd fragment for return 
setFragment(fragmentSearch);//  I put second fragment on the screen 

//Part from 2nd Class
public FragmentAdd fragmentAdd;
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("BARCODE",result.getText());//transfer of gathered data
                fragmentAdd.setArguments(bundle);
                setFragment(fragmentAdd);//and go back



//onCreateView of fragmentAdd (1st Class)
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String A = bundle.getString("BARCODE");
            txProductName.setText(A);//It doesn't change anything and doesn't arises any error
}
```